# Upload a user picked directory in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R shiny app that requires multiple files (all found within the same folder) to be uploaded. I also know the names of the files to look for.

Is there any way to upload these files other than via `fileInput(..., multiple = TRUE)`? Ideally, I would have the user upload the whole directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the library `shinyFiles` to let the user pic a folder somewhere on their local disk. Then in the server you can use the user input to load all the files that you need from this folder.

**Example**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

### UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton('directory_select', 'Select a directory', title='Select a directory'),
  textOutput('directory_name')
)

### Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  volumes <- getVolumes()
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory_select', roots=volumes, session=session)
  dirname <- reactive({parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory_select)})

  ## Observe input dir. changes
  observe({
    if(!is.null(dirname)){
      print(dirname())
      output$directory_name <- renderText(dirname())
      ## Load files here
      # csv <- read.csv(paste0(dirname(), '/filename1.csv'))
      # rdata <- load(paste0(dirname(), '/filename2.Rdata'))
      # etc.
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: I would be surprised if Shiny's JavaScript was allowed to browse my (the client's) disk. Fortunately, the code above does not seem to work. Also, the `shinyFiles` docs say: "This package extends the functionality of shiny by providing an API for client side access **to the server file system**." So this answer does not apply to remotely hosted Shiny apps.