# Is there a way to upload a directory with multiple folders and read all the files within the folders in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing an app where:

1. A user can upload a directory of folders containing multiple files
2. The files within each folder are extracted and read.

I don't know the names of the folders, but I do know that every file within the folders is the same file type (.json). Essentially, I want to bypass the folders and pull the files directly and read them to a list. For example, based on [Upload a user picked directory in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551352/upload-a-user-picked-directory-in-r-shiny) (the code of which actually doesn't work, but it's the closest example I could find), it would look something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
 shinyDirButton("directory", "Select Directory", "Please select a directory"),
 textOutput("files")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  volumes <- getVolumes()
  shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", defaultRoot = volumes, session = session)
  
  files_acquired_from_directory <- # some function to extract the files from the folders similar to fileInput()
  
  files <- files_acquired_from_directory()
  fileList <- map(files$datapath, read_json)
  output$files <- renderPrint(fileList())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I try using `shinyDirButton` and `shinyDirChoose`, all I get is an empty user-interface, so this might not be the best way to do it - the above is just an example of what I'm looking for.

Thank you so much for any help/assistance/guidance!!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to "upload a directory", I suggest one of two paths: (1) `shiny::fileInput` supports the argument `multiple=TRUE` (ref: https://mastering-shiny.org/action-transfer.html#server), so the user can select one or more files for uploading. From there, your app can easily access each of the original filenames and the data within them. Or (2), have the user upload a zip-file. With that, you can list the files stored in it and extract them manually.

Comment: Note that `shinyFiles` is *"providing an API for client side access to the server file system"*, so `shinyFiles::shinyDir*` is showing you a directory on the server, not the client. The only time that this would facilitate "uploading" (really, "identifying") a directory (with some nested directories/files) is when it is run locally on the user's own computer; this is what is meant in the package by *"As many shiny apps are run locally this is equivalent to accessing the filesystem of the users own computer"* (ref: https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles).

Comment: I will try the zip file! My original app uses `fileInput(multiple=TRUE)` but the way we get our data, it comes in a directory that’s been automatically sorted into folders, which means we have to go in manually and copy/paste them into a single directory and I wanted to avoid that. Can you use `fileInput()` for zip files?

Comment: Yes, the user can upload a previously-created zipfile using that. (It does not automatically create a zipfile, though, so that is a step that just be accomplished outside of shiny.)

Comment: It worked! So awesome, thanks for the taking the time to help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @r2evans, I learned that I can put it in a zip file and read it from there.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "Upload file", accept = "zip"),
  tableOutput("check")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  files <- reactive({
    d <- req(input$file)
    u <- unzip(d$datapath)
    u
  })
  
  dataList <- reactive({
    files <- files()
    jsons <- files$Name
    data <- purrr::map(jsons, read_json)
    data
  })

  output$check <- renderTable(dataList())
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```